# How to convert gorm.DB query to its string representation

Tags: go, go-gorm

Let's say I have a gorm.DB object in Go, and I want to extract and assert the query I've built to see it was built correctly.
How can I compare the "string" representation of the query to this object ?

Comment: please put your attempt and put some part of your code

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure your `gorm` is up to date.**

1. Using [`ToSQL`](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#ToSQL)

example:

```golang
sql := DB.ToSQL(func(tx *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return tx.Model(&User{}).Where("id = ?", 100).Limit(10).Order("age desc").Find(&[]User{})
})
sql //=> SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE id = 100 AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY age desc LIMIT 10
```

2. Using [`DryRun Mode`](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#DryRun-Mode)

example:

```golang
stmt := db.Session(&Session{DryRun: true}).First(&user, 1).Statement
stmt.SQL.String() //=> SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $1 ORDER BY `id`
stmt.Vars         //=> []interface{}{1}
```

3. Using [`Debug`](https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html#Debug)

example:

```golang
db.Debug().Where("name = ?", "jinzhu").First(&User{})
```

Comment: stmt.SQL.String() always evaluates to nil even though the query yield proper result

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use `Debug()` to print raw sql built by gorm to stdout.

```golang
db.Debug().Where("name = ?", "jinzhu").First(&User{})
```

FYI https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html#Debug